# MissingAdminPermissions when trying to create shifts using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are currently experiencing some issues when using the Microsoft Graph API.

We have already registered an app in Azure AD and also gave it certain permissions:

- Schedule.ReadWrite.All
- Team.ReadBasic.All
- Group.Read.All

GET Requests are working fine and I can access the schedules and shifts.

However if I want create a shift I get the following response (403 Forbidden):

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "Forbidden",
      "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"Forbidden\",\"message\":\"Sorry, you need to be an admin to do this.\",\"details\":[],\"innererror\":{\"code\":\"MissingAdminPermissions\"}}}",
      "innerError": {
         "date": "2020-08-28T08:11:25",
         "request-id": "..."
      }
   }
}
```

I am using the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST 
     --url 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/schedule/shifts' 
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
     --header "MS-APP-ACTS-AS: {client-_id}"  
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer ey...' 
     --data @graph_api.json
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I really don't know what's the issue here.

Comment: I have same problem. Did you resolve it ?

Comment: No couldn't solve it yet

Comment: I think MS document is incorrect on "required permission". Most of authors test their functions with global administrator right.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Do you have any progress in this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Is the user you are setting the app to act as an owner of the Team? It might be that the app has the correct permissions but the user it's acting as doesn't have permission to manage the Team/Shift.

> --header "MS-APP-ACTS-AS: {client-_id}"

Answer (score -2):

You are missing Schedule.ReadWrite.All

[Link for Ref.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-post-shifts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: Hi AnkUser,

thanks for your response but as I already said my app has been granted this permission in Azure AD and I am still experiencing this exception

Comment: could you try removing and adding all the rights again. May be this will trigger internally some process to reapply security changes? I do not see any other issue other than security rights.

Comment: I will try this out. I am not an admin in Azure so granting the permissions can take a few days. I will come back to you :)

Comment: I have added the permissions again but the same error appears again. At this point I am really clueless. I follow the Docs but somehow I am missing something.

Comment: Ok, Did you tried your request with Postman? If not could you try with it first